# Update an progress-bar with an percentage number?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I have an animated progress-bar, in my Js Code i have a variable which is a percentage number `Puverg`, how can I update the progress-bar to have the same progress as the percentage number?

```js
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance=countDownDate-now;
    var vergangen=intervall-distance;
    var Puverg=(vergangen/intervall)*100;
    var Puebrig=100-Puverg;
}, 1000);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
body{
  font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container{
  margin: 100px auto;
  margin-top: 330px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.progress2{
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress-bar2{
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition-property: width,background-color;
}

.progress-moved .progress-bar2{
  background-color:#f3c623;
  animation: progress 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes progress{
  0%{
    width:0%;
    background:#f9bcca;
  }
  100%{
    width:100%;
    background:#f3c623;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px #f3c623;
  }
}

.icon{
  color:#f3c623;
  animation: icon 5s infinite;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-right: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@keyframes icon{
  0%{
    opacity: .2;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #f3c623;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #f3c623;
  }
}

.loader{
  --p:0;
  animation: p 5s steps(100) infinite;
  counter-reset: p var(--p);
  font-size: 2.1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 325px;
  color:#f3c623;
}
.loader::after{
  content: counter(p) "%";
}

@keyframes p{
  90%,100%{
    --p: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <i class="fas fas-3x fa battery-full icon"></i>
  <div class="progress2 progress-moved">
    <div class="progress-bar2"></div>
    <div class="loader" style="--n: 1; --f:0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  CSS.registerProperty({
    name: "--p",
    syntax: "<integer>",
      initialValue: 0,
      inherits: true,

  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which element is your `progress bar`.

Let's say you have two divs to form your progress bar.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Set your own width and height for the progress bar.

```
#container {
    width: 'Set a width here';
    height: 'Set a height here';
    text-align: left;
}
#progress {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Don't forget to add your own styles.

Just change the width of your `progress` div as your progress changes.
Set the width as `10%` if your progress is `10%`.
But you need to set certain styles for your progress bar.

```
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance=countDownDate-now;
    var vergangen=intervall-distance;
    var Puverg=(vergangen/intervall)*100;
    var Puebrig=100-Puverg;

    /* Assuming Puebrig is the current percentage value */
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = Puebrig+'%';

}, 1000);
```